# Trigger to enforce constraint that a department has only one department head

Tags: triggers

Suppose I have following schema :

DEPARTMENT ( idDepartment, DepartmentName)

EMPLOYEE (idEmployee, FirstName, LastName, idDepartment, Phone, Email)

How to write a trigger so that a department can only have 1 employee as the department head when updating or adding a new employee table

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.